# Trigger event after bootstrap modal is full loaded in GUI

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am opening bootstrap modal with:

```
$('#myModal').modal({ remote: '/AccountsContact/ModalAssignCustomer?iACCO_KEY=' + iACCO_KEY });
```

My problem is that I need to read some values from modal. I would like to do that, when modal is finished loading and shown in the GUI. (before modal is shown in the GUI controls inside modal are not generated yet).

I know for this event:

```
    $(window).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() { 
    $('#code').modal('hide');
    alert('hidden');
});
```

but problem here is that event is triggered before modal is loaded on the GUI - thus all the fields inside modal are not generated yet and I am not able to read from them.

Is there a way to trigger event after modal is fully loaded inside GUI and all controls inside modal visible?

Comment: I would think for your purposes you would want to rely on `loaded.bs.modal` which triggers after remote data has been loaded.  But I should note; `remote` was depreciated in 3.3.0 and removed in v4.  Are you sure you can rely on it for your project?

Comment: A little workaround that could help here:
when opening the modal --> append a hidden input field, div or whatever with a class, that does not exist yet. (eg. `<input class="tmp hidden" />`).

then check with `while($('.tmp').length < 1)` if the element is created. Due to append it should be added to the DOM as last element --> therefore when the element with this class exists, the modal should be fully loaded

Comment: @RobertC - loaded.bs.modal solved my problem. I guess it would be a problem when we update bootstrap version, but for now, it's more than fine. What is used in V4 instead of loaded.bs.modal? Please post your comment as answer so I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below code, which might help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    });
        $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            alert('The modal is fully shown.');
            $(this).find('p').text("This is changed text after alert");
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Events - shown.bs.modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>The <strong>shown.bs.modal</strong> event occurs when the modal is fully shown.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The event that you're looking for would be `loaded.bs.modal`, which triggers after `remote` data has been fully loaded.

As noted in my earlier comment, `remote` was depreciated in 3.3.0 and fully removed in version 4.x.  You can replicate the functionality pretty simply with a bit of jQuery and I encourage you to explore the innumerable solutions here on SO.  My *personal preference* is something like the below code:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
  $($(this).data("target") + ' .modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-lg').removeClass('modal-sm').addClass('modal-' + $(this).data("size"));
  $($(this).data("target") + ' .modal-content').load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

In the above example the modal trigger is bound to `body` so you can access it via elements generated outside the DOM.  You can still use `data-toggle` and specifying a remote URL is as simple as defining the `href` attribute, though this does limit you to `<a>` as the trigger (though it could easily be modified).

The first thing the above code does though, is remove any sizing classes on the modal and clears any pre-existing modal content since it relies on a single modal dialog box to populate.

I also like to specify which size modal box should be activated via `data-size` so the above code reflects that as well.  Again... a lot of personal preference going on in that option.